# Pass a dynamic URL field into an iframe without server side coding

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, dynamic

need some help on the below, as, unfortunately, I am unable to figure it out by myself :(

1. User gets redirected to a form (served via an iframe) which includes a dynamic URL: website.com/form?id=123
2. The code which serves up the page reads that value ("123") from the “id” parameter in the page’s URL.
3. The script then writes that value on the end of the URL in the “data-url” attribute, like in the example code snippet below.

```html
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="iframe.com/to/abc123?id=123" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" ></div> 
<script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.iframe.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() 
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get it to work...

Thanks much!

Comment: Got stuck on parsing the id from the URL...

Comment: Is this code executing inside the frame? Is it trying to read the current browser url or iframe url?

Comment: The code is on the site (not the iframe), but aims at changing the iframe url by reading the id tag in the current browser url

Comment: So if I understand it right, user goes to "website.com/form?id=123" using a browser, that page needs to add a IFRAME with url as `iframe.com/to/abc123?id=123`? do you have a sample nonworking live page also?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure why you are facing issue with this task. Below is how I would get the ID from the current URL

```
url = document.location.href;
var paramId = new URL(url).searchParams.get("id");

var frameElement = document.getElementById("typef_orm_frame");
frameElement.src = "https://example.com/to/abc" + paramId + "?id=" +paramId;
```

Here is the JSFiddle for the demo

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lswuxj8/1/